# truffle test fail when --network flag is set

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, truffle, go-ethereum

### truffle config

Below is my `truffle.js` file. As you can see, `development` and `privateLive` are exactly the same.

```
// truffle.js
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      provider: () => new PrivateKeyProvider(privateKey, sidechainEndpoint),
      host: 'http://222.200.180.185',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*', // eslint-disable-line camelcase
      from: '0xab2ec9c41aee37c87466fe54194bb88ba5c5ca31'
    },

    privateLive: {
      provider: () => new PrivateKeyProvider(privateKey, sidechainEndpoint),
      host: 'http://222.200.180.185',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*', // eslint-disable-line camelcase
      from: '0xab2ec9c41aee37c87466fe54194bb88ba5c5ca31'
      },

    ...
}
```

### test case

I have an empty test file `test/test.js`.

```js
// test/test.js
// empty
```

### the bug

Below command succeeds.

```sh
$ ./node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js test test/testp.js
Using network 'development'.



  0 passing (1ms)
```

However, below command fails.

```sh
$ ./node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js --network privateLive test test/test.js
Using network 'privateLive'.

Transaction: 0x4d11ca4f12122d8b70ad71bd272ef7fd01a70a96025c3b2249237e5631287507 exited with an error (status 0).
Please check that the transaction:
    - satisfies all conditions set by Solidity `require` statements.
    - does not trigger a Solidity `revert` statement.
```

Could anyone tell me what's the difference and why `truffle` behaved like that.

I also want to know how can I get the reason why transaction failed. I tried `eth.getTransaction` and `eth.getTransactionReceipt` and found nothing helpful.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: AFAIK, Truffle does not support `--network` flag for test.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to debug the transaction using truffle debug, as follow:

```
truffle debug 0x4d11ca4f12122d8b70ad71bd272ef7fd01a70a96025c3b2249237e5631287507 --network=privateLive
```

See more about how to debug using truffle [here](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/debugging-your-contracts)